# How can I create a slideshow in js, from mysql image file paths?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a mysql db product table with product image file paths, quantities and prices. I select the products marked for slideshow and keep their data in html table slidesdata_tbl. I want to create a slideshow  from the image file paths in the table but no matter what I do, I can't get it to work. There are similar questions asked but none of the answers helps me. Any help will be appreciated.

```js
// Build a slide-show from images.    
            var slides_array = [];
            $("#slidesdata_tbl tr").each(function() {  
                var rowDataArray = [];
                var actualData = $(this).find("td");
                if (actualData.length > 0) {
                    actualData.each(function() {
                        rowDataArray.push($(this));
                    });
                    slides_array.push(rowDataArray);
                }        
            })    
            console.log(slides_array);
            let slide1_img = document.getElementById("slide1_img");
            let slide2_img = document.getElementById("slide2_img");
            let slide3_img = document.getElementById("slide3_img");
            let slide4_img = document.getElementById("slide4_img");
            let n = 0;
            setInterval(()=>{displaySlides()}, 2000);
            function displaySlides() {
                slide1_img.src = slides_array[n];
                slide2_img.src = slides_array[n+1];
                slide3_img.src = slides_array[n+2];
                slide4_img.src = slides_array[n+3];
                n++;
                if (n === slides_array.length) {
                    n=0;
                }    
            }
        })
```

```html
 <table id="slidesdata_tbl" class="slidesdata_tbl"> 
            <tbody>
                <% if(data.length){ for(var i = 0; i< data.length; i++) {%>
                    <tr>
                        <td><img src="<%=data[i].prod_image_file%>" class="slideimg" name="slideimg" id="slideimg" ></td>
                        <td><%=data[i].quantity_id%> class="quantity" id="quantity"</td>
                        <td><%=data[i].saleprice%> class="saleprice" id="saleprice"</td>
                    </tr>    
                <%} }else { %> 
                    <p>Slideshow list is empty!</p>
                <% } %> 
            </tbody>
        </table>            
       <div class="slideshow" onload="displaySlides()">
            <img src="" id="slide1_img" class="slide1_img">
            <img src="" id="slide2_img" class="slide2_img">
            <img src="" id="slide3_img" class="slide3_img">
            <img src="" id="slide4_img" class="slide4_img">
       </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this out. I changed my code as follows and it now works.

```js
// Build a slide-show from images.    
            var slides_array = [];
            for ( let row of slidesdata_tbl.rows) {
                for( let cell of row.cells) {
                    slides_array.push(cell.innerText)
                }
            }
            let slide1_img = document.getElementById("slide1_img");
            let slide2_img = document.getElementById("slide2_img");
            let slide3_img = document.getElementById("slide3_img");
            let slide4_img = document.getElementById("slide4_img");
            let n = 0;
            setInterval(()=>{displaySlides()}, 2000);
            function displaySlides() {
                slide1_img.src = slides_array[n];
                slide2_img.src = slides_array[n+1];
                slide3_img.src = slides_array[n+2];
                slide4_img.src = slides_array[n+3];
                n++;
                if (n === slides_array.length) {
                    n=0;
                }    
            }
        })
```

```html
<table id="slidesdata_tbl" class="slidesdata_tbl"> 
            <tbody>
                <% if(data.length){ for(var i = 0; i< data.length; i++) {%>
                    <tr>
                        <td><%=data[i].prod_image_file%></td>
                        <td><%=data[i].quantity_id%> class="quantity" id="quantity"</td>
                        <td><%=data[i].saleprice%> class="saleprice" id="saleprice"</td>
                    </tr>    
                <%} }else { %> 
                    <p>Slideshow list is empty!</p>
                <% } %> 
            </tbody>
        </table>            
       <div class="slideshow" onload="displaySlides()">
            <img src="" id="slide1_img" class="slide1_img">
            <img src="" id="slide2_img" class="slide2_img">
            <img src="" id="slide3_img" class="slide3_img">
            <img src="" id="slide4_img" class="slide4_img">
       </div>
```